# HTML Angular form appears twice on page

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm having what probably seems like a noob problem. I have a simple Angular controller that controls a form on a page. The markup for the form is pretty straight forward. When I load the page, I see the form rendered twice, rather tha once as it should be. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>CREATE</h2>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="form-container" ng-controller="NewPostQuestionCtrl">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form.postQuestionForm" ng-submit="createPostQuestion(postQuestion)" class="new_post_item" novalidate>
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.token" ng-init="postQuestion.token='<%= form_authenticity_token %>'">
                        <input name="employer_id" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.employer_id" ng-init="postQuestion.employer_id='<%= current_employer.id %>'">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Question</label>
                            <textarea class="question-textbox" name="question" ng-model="postQuestion.question" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input class="" name="image" ng-model="postQuestion.image" type="file" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Publish Question</label>
                            <select class="" name="published" ng-model="postQuestion.published" required>
                                <option value="true">Publish</option>
                                <option value="false">Don't Publish</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <input class="submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Publish Post" ng-disabled="form.postQuestion.$invalid">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('NewPostQuestionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.form = {}
    $scope.postQuestion = {
        token: $scope.token,
        employer_id: $scope.employer_id,
        question: $scope.question,
        published: $scope.published,
        image: $scope.image
    };
}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will help anyone, but I figured out my problem and it was a really obvious oversight.

I have two `<%= yield %>` tags in my `application.html.erb` that are nested inside an if/else statement. The second tag was outside the statement, which was evaluating to true, causing my partial to be rendered twice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the full HTML for your application to hand? Is it only the form that is rendered twice or also the `h2` element? Is it possible you have the `ng-view` directive twice in your markup?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is loading twice.

Check in your .js file where you map the urls with controller. If you have the controller set in the app.js or any_file.js(where you map url with controller and views), you dont have to include the ng-controller in the html..